# All CPU busy, high avg load, but tasks CPU usage don't add up

Tags: linux

Looking at the outputs below, could someone tell me what is causing the high load?

CentOs 6 
Linux 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 (4 CPU)

Im suspecting that `sar` numbers are high but Im not experienced with that.

```
[root@a1 ~]# sar -b 1 3
01:08:22 PM       tps      rtps      wtps   bread/s   bwrtn/s
01:08:23 PM    225.74      7.92    217.82    269.31  13362.38
01:08:24 PM    116.67     74.51     42.16   4062.75    188.24
01:08:25 PM    161.22     64.29     96.94   3240.82    840.82
Average:       167.77     48.84    118.94   2522.26   4821.26

[root@a1 ~]# sar -w 1 3
01:09:46 PM    proc/s   cswch/s
01:09:47 PM     13.13   6662.63
01:09:48 PM     17.82   3891.09
01:09:49 PM     20.20   5031.31
Average:        17.06   5186.29
```

top output (shows high load avegare)
[image: top output]

htop (video, shows all busy CPU)
 
https://www.lot-art.com/htop.mp4

top (video, shows what each CPU core is doing)
 
https://www.lot-art.com/top.mp4

`ps auxf` output
 
https://www.lot-art.com/ps_auxf.txt

`pidstat -w` output
 
https://www.lot-art.com/pidstat_w.txt

Comment: @anx Thank you. `Linux 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64` . I added `pidstat -w` output to my post.

Comment: This virtulal machine is using almost all its available CPU. A small part is in contention with other VMs on the host. Your VPS provider might be overcommitting resources. But the major thing is MySQL. You should work on optimizing database queries and anything else that mysqltuner.pl recommends. Buy more CPU if it's truly necessary. Further, you seem to be using cPanel/WHM. You should get rid of that and build a standard web server.

Comment: I think there is low memory situation. Swap is used 50%. The problem is in mysql memory configuration. This database must have 30-50% of full RAM. Also an right indexes usage can reduce CPU load by 10 time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your high usage is from mysql. You have some queries consuming too much resources, php-cgi is left waiting for the database queries to finish and httpd is left waiting php-cgi to return. If you determine which queries are responsible for this consumption, you can optimize those queries.

And your load is not that high. You have 4 processors, any load close to 4 is not high. A max load of 5.4 is acceptable.